# in Python run ipython notebook occured File "<stdin>", line 1 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

I installed tensorflow+python in the Max OS, following some resources around the web.
env pameters:Mac OS 10.12 + python2.7+tensorflow 0.5.0
When I try to open notebook,I occured an error like that:

```
****MacBook:code ****$ python

Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 26 2016, 12:10:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ipython notebook
File "<stdin>", line 1
ipython notebook
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print  ‘hello'


python[notebook])
```

When I check the clause,result is:

```
****MacBook:****$ pip install --user ipython[notebook】
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in 
/Users/****/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages  (from      
html5lib>=0.99999999->bleach->nbconvert->notebook; extra == "notebook”->ipython[notebook])
```

When I use print command,result is :

```
>>> print "hello"
    hello
>>> print(hello)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
 >>> print("hello")
 hello
```

I can’t find solution,could you give me any useful guidance,Thank you very much.

Comment: `ipython notebook` is not a Python command so you should not type it at a Python prompt. As for the second issue, you are trying to print a variable named `hello` in the second case and haven't defined it. You should probably look at a Python tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.I list the case print(***) just want to explain this issue is not  python compatibility.I uninstall python and reinstall it using “sudo easy_install ipython”,it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The command "ipython notebook" is not executed in python REPL, it is executed in shell.

`****MacBook:code ****$ ipython notebook` will be OK.

Comment: ****MacBook:notebooks ***$ ipython notebook
-bash: ipython: command not found    Do I need add env variable?

Comment: Did you install ipython? You can use `pip install ipython` to install.